# SQL Server 2008 - Add XML Declaration to XML Output

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding

I've been battling with this one for a few days now, I'm looking to automate an XML output with the below syntax

```
 SELECT (
   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
   FOR XML PATH('DataVersion'), 
     TYPE
   ),
   (  
   SELECT CoNum,
     CoName,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),AccountToDate,103) 'DLA',
     LAFileNet
   FROM @XMLOutput  
   FOR XML PATH('Company'),
     TYPE  
   )
 FOR XML PATH(''),
   ROOT('Companies')
```

Which creates the below output

```
<Companies>
  <DataVersion>15/11/2010</DataVersion>
  <Company>
    <CoNum>111</CoNum>
    <CoName>ABCLmt</CoName>
    <DLA>12/12/2010</DLA>
    <LAFileNet>1234</LAFileNet>
  </Company>
  <Company>
    <CoNum>222</CoNum>
    <CoName>DEFLmt</CoName>
    <DLA>12/12/2007</DLA>
    <LAFileNet>5678</LAFileNet>
  </Company>
</Companies>
```

What I'm struggling with is how to add the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>` to the top of the output??

Update 1: Would I be correct in thinking I need to create a XML schema in SQL server to define the xsl:output. Then assign the output to that schema?

Update 2: Have since found these links
http://forums.asp.net/t/1455808.aspx -- Check out comment from Jian Kang. Also
http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.xml/topic60022.aspx

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: FYI: That string is the XML declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add xml encoding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to xml Output in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002403/how-to-add-xml-encoding-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-xml-output-in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

Concatenate this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>` with your XML, converted to varchar(max).

### Details

I agree with [j0N45](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577228/j0n45) that the schema will not change anything. As [the answer he references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002485/2266979) points out:

> You have to add it manually.

I provided some example code to do so in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207366/2266979). Basically, you `CONVERT` the XML into `varchar` or `nvarchar` and then concatenate it with the XML declaration, such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>`.

However, it's important to choose the right encoding. SQL Server produces non-Unicode strings according to its collation settings. By default, that will be governed by the database collation settings, which you can determine using this SQL:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('ExampleDatabaseName', 'Collation');
```

[A common default collation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bfdc32d3-3d36-4d63-8d87-6ee972fd8130/on-sqllatin1generalcp1cias-sql-server-2008-default-collation) is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", which has a code page of 1252. You can retrieve the code page with this SQL:

```
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'CodePage') AS 'CodePage';
```

For code page 1252, you should use an encoding name of "[windows-1252](http://www.iana.org/assignments/charset-reg/windows-1252)". The use of "ISO-8859-1" is inaccurate. You can test that using the "bullet" character: •. It has a Unicode Code Point value of 8226 (Hex 2022). You can generate the character in SQL reliably, regardless of collation, using this code:

```
SELECT NCHAR(8226);
```

It has also has a code point of 149 in the windows-1252 code page, so you if you are using the common, default collation of "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", then you can also produce it using:

```
SELECT CHAR(149);
```

However, CHAR(149) won't be a bullet in all collations. For example, if you try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(1),char(149)) COLLATE Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_BIN;
```

You don't get a bullet at all.

[The "ISO-8859-1" code page is Windows-28591](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). None of the SQL Server collations (in 2005 anyway) use that code page. You can get a full list of code pages using:

```
SELECT [Name], [Description], [CodePage] = COLLATIONPROPERTY([Name], 'CodePage')
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
ORDER BY [CodePage] DESC;
```

You can further verify that "ISO-8859-1" is the wrong choice by trying to use it in SQL itself. The following SQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><test>•</test>');
```

Will produce XML which does not contain a bullet. Indeed, it won't produce any character, because ISO-8859-1 has no character defined for code point 149.

SQL Server handles Unicode strings differently. With Unicode strings (`nvarchar`), ["there is no need for different code pages to handle different sets of characters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx). However, SQL Server does NOT use "UTF-8" encoding. If you try to use it within SQL itself:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>•</test>');
```

You will get an error:

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 38,
>   unable to switch the encoding

Rather, SQL uses "UCS-2" encoding, so this will work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UCS-2"?><test>•</test>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers to your question [How to add xml encoding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to xml Output in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002403/how-to-add-xml-encoding-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-xml-output-in).

I don't think creating a schema would change anything, because it is only used to validation.

Cheers

Comment: You have created a circular reference as your suggested link already refers back to this link.