# adding encoding information to the result of FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Script, which returns a XML using FOR XML in SQL 2008. Is there any way to add the version and encoding information in the beginning of the output. Eventually, i am planning to save the output in a file.

For example, right now my output looks like this

```
<Agents>
  <Agent id="1">
    <Name>Mike</Name>
    <Location>Sanfrancisco</Location>
  </Agent>
  <Agent id="2">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Location>NY</Location>
  </Agent>
</Agents>
```

I would like to append the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the beginning of the Xml output

So i want the output something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Agents>
 <Agent id="1">
   <Name>Mike</Name>
   <Location>Sanfrancisco</Location>
 </Agent>
<Agent id="2">
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Location>NY</Location>
</Agent>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @gbn points out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215182/2266979) and on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002485/2266979), "[the XML data is stored internally as ucs-2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28SQL.90%29.aspx)", and SQL Server doesn't include it when producing the data. However, you can convert the XML to a string and append the XML declaration at the beginning manually. However, simply using UTF-8 in the declaration would be inaccurate. The Unicode string which SQL produces is in UCS-2. For example, this will fail:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(XML,N'<x>' + NCHAR(10176) + N'</x>')));
```

with error:

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 38,
>   unable to switch the encoding

This, on the other hand, will work as expected:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UCS-2"?>' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(XML,N'<x>' + NCHAR(10176) + N'</x>')));
```

Here is code which will produce the full, declaration-laden XML string you seek for your example data:

```
DECLARE @Agents TABLE
(
    AgentID int,
    AgentName nvarchar(50),
    AgentLocation nvarchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO @Agents (AgentID, AgentName, AgentLocation) VALUES (1, N'Mike', N'Sanfrancisco');
INSERT INTO @Agents (AgentID, AgentName, AgentLocation) VALUES (2, N'John', N'NY');

WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        (
            SELECT
                AgentID AS '@id',
                AgentName AS 'Name',
                AgentLocation AS 'Location'
            FROM    @Agents
            FOR     XML PATH('Agent'), ROOT('Agents'), TYPE
        ) AS AgentXML
), FullStringTable AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UCS-2"?>' +
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max),AgentXML) AS FullString
    FROM        BaseData
)
SELECT
    AgentXML AS OriginalXML,
    FullString,
    CONVERT(xml,FullString) AS FullStringConvertedToXML
FROM        FullStringTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server internally always uses <strike>utf-16</strike> ucs-2 so you *could* just append it like we did. That is, SQL Server would never generate anything with "utf-8".

Edit: after some digging:

- http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.xml/topic60022.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1455808.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you will not be attempting to manipulate the results as TSQL XML then the simplest thing to do will be create a varchar with the string you wish to append then add the XML to it using a CAST statemnt to convert the XML to varchar.

```
declare @testXML as XML
declare @testPrefix as varchar(255)
set @testPrefix = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
set @testXML = '<Agents>  <Agent id="1">    <Name>Mike</Name>    <Location>Sanfrancisco</Location>  </Agent>  <Agent id="2">    <Name>John</Name>    <Location>NY</Location>  </Agent></Agents>'

select @testPrefix
Select @testXML
select @testPrefix + CAST(@testXML as varchar(max))
```