# How to add additional XML node on top of my SQL generated XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have generated XML from a SQL Server `FOR XML PATH` statement as shown here:

```
USE MySQLDB

SELECT * 
FROM BillTable
FOR XML PATH ('BillAdd'), ROOT ('BillAddRq')
```

And this is the result:

```
<BillAddRq>
    <BillAdd>
        <TxnID>2432-1071510295</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-16T01:44:55</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2015-12-15T22:38:33</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1450190313</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>413</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef_ListID>E0000-933272656</VendorRef_ListID>
        <VendorRef_FullName>Timberloft Lumber</VendorRef_FullName>
        <APAccountRef_ListID>C0000-933270541</APAccountRef_ListID>
        <APAccountRef_FullName>Accounts Payable</APAccountRef_FullName>
        <TxnDate>2016-12-01T00:00:00</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>80.50000</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef_ListID>50000-933272659</TermsRef_ListID>
        <TermsRef_FullName>1% 10 Net 30</TermsRef_FullName>
        <IsPaid>0</IsPaid>
    </BillAdd>
    <BillAdd>
        <TxnID>243A-1071510389</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-16T01:46:29</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2015-12-15T22:38:33</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1450190313</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>414</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef_ListID>C0000-933272656</VendorRef_ListID>
        <VendorRef_FullName>Perry Windows &amp; Doors</VendorRef_FullName>
        <APAccountRef_ListID>C0000-933270541</APAccountRef_ListID>
        <APAccountRef_FullName>Accounts Payable</APAccountRef_FullName>
        <TxnDate>2016-12-02T00:00:00</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-01-01T00:00:00</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>50.00000</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef_ListID>10000-933272658</TermsRef_ListID>
        <TermsRef_FullName>Net 30</TermsRef_FullName>
        <IsPaid>0</IsPaid>
    </BillAdd>
</BillAddRq>
```

Now, I'd like to encapsulate the above with these nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="15.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">

         //above generated xml//

    </QBXMLMsgsRq>        
</QBXML>
```

How will I achieve this in a SQL Query I created above?

I am new to SQL Server and XML. I am trying to generate this XML directly from my database and vice versa to make it more efficient and faster — let my SQL directly communicate with XML.

ATTEMPT 1:

```
USE MySQLDB;  
GO  
DECLARE @myDoc XML;         
SET @myDoc = '<QBXML>         
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">                  
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>         
</QBXML>'; 

SET @myDoc.modify('         
insert

    -- instead of inserting string here.. I would like to insert here the query I made above

into (/QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRq)[1]');

SELECT @myDoc;
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```
USE MySQLDB;  
GO  
DECLARE @myDoc XML;         
SET @myDoc = '<QBXML>         
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">                  
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>         
</QBXML>'; 

DECLARE @qry XML;
SET @qry = (SELECT * FROM BillTable FOR XML PATH ('BillAdd'), ROOT ('BillAddRq'));

-- SELECT @qry;

SET @myDoc.modify('insert @qry
    into (/QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRq)[1]');

SELECT @myDoc;
```

Comment: Why not add the strings before and after?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184163/sql-server-2008-add-xml-declaration-to-xml-output and use Google if necessary. There are already very many articles about this topic that should help.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi I am not so familiar but I will try to add string before and after..

Comment: You could also use [XML.modify()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) to [insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/insert-xml-dml) the XML at the appropriate document location.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I followed the documentation you shared but I am struggling to insert the query instead of string in the documentation. I will appreciate further help here. Please check my edited Attempt 1. Thanks.

Comment: I created another attempt above but still not working. The @@qry is actually working but the how-to insert in @@myDoc.Modify is what I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to construct your XML result, consider the following three alternatives...

Use XML.modify() to insert the BillTable XML into an XML scalar variable (which includes the `?qbxml` XML processing instruction):

```sql
declare @BillTableXml xml = (
  select *
  from BillTable
  for xml path('BillAdd'), root('BillAddRq')
);

declare @myDoc xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="15.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>        
</QBXML>';

set @myDoc.modify('
  insert sql:variable("@BillTableXml")
  into (/QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRq)[1]
');

select @myDoc as Result;
```

Use a nested query to construct the entire XML result (which does not, however, include the `?qbxml` XML processing instruction):

```sql
select
  'stopOnError' as [QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRq/@onError],
  (
    select *
    from BillTable
    for xml path('BillAdd'), root('BillAddRq'), type
  ) as [QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRq]
for xml path('');
```

Or use an XQuery to construct the entire XML result (which also includes the `?qbxml` XML processing instruction):

```sql
select BillTableXml.query('
  <?qbxml version="15.0"?>,
  <QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      { /BillAddRq }
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>        
  </QBXML>
') as Result
from (
  select *
  from BillTable
  for xml path('BillAdd'), root('BillAddRq'), type
) Data (BillTableXml);
```

Comment: @AlwaysLearing Thanks for these! I can say we're almost there. Most of them works except the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` which was not captured by the first solution.

Comment: At last! I realized why `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is not necessary to be included in the xml above because it is a declaration of the xml itself. I tested the above result and it is working on my end. Thanks so much for this solutions. It works.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to leave that in there. Internally the XML data type in SQL Server doesn't preserve the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration because it's in a stored semi-parsed format - and so must have come from XML by definition.